# How to find the directory of laravel installation in Windows

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I installed laravel in my pc but forgot the directory I installed in.How can I find where I installed it if it's possible?I used composer to install laravel but I have forgotten the directory.

Comment: Please share more information.

Comment: from where you have installed? command prompt?

Comment: I think you use composer or laravel installer to install your laravel project, this is implies that you use the terminal or command line, just open you terminal like you did before you install laravel, if you had not change directory before install laravel it will be in the directory where you usualy open you terminal

Comment: @Chirag Patel from command prompt

Comment: @yvesdaxmaz I changed directory during installation process that's why  php artisan serve fails

Comment: ok doesn't matter. If you haven't code anything in it. find new one from here [laravel installation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation)

Comment: @syam.k  I installed laravel in a folder in my pc but can't seem to remember it.So I was asking if there is a way I can use the cmd to find laravel projects  and their location in my PC?

Comment: What OS you are using ?

Comment: @ChiragPatel I wanted to see if there was a way to find laravel projects in a PC in case one forgets their directory, but due to the urgency I just got a new one as you said .Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

This is the default directory of laravel in windows

```
C:\Users\YourPcName\AppData\Local\Composer\files\laravel
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be a little bit mad, but try search `"artisan"` text on search window. and it'll show laravel project folders.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not a laravel problem. 
But generally people are using wamp64/www or xampp/htdocs
Or cmd automatically opening c:/users/name.
If you can't find, just setup filesearcher programs.